# angular 9 and collapsible bootstrap menu

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, navigation

I have a bootstrap 4 collapsible menu (in angular 9), when i resize i get the hamburger as planned. When i click on it it expands, but when i click on it again it will not fold back in, you see it quickly flash, but it wont stay folded in.

I already looked at the answers here but they do not seem to solve the issue.  As far as i can see i have not loaded the bootstrap twice, that was my 1st thought. Next  i took the lines to load it from the cdn network from bootstrap itself again, just in case and i also tried varying the order in which the scripts were loaded.

None of this worked.

The code to create the collapsible menu us also straight from bootstrap itself. No doubt something silly but i cant see it.

My html code is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="line"></span> 
        <span class="line"></span> 
        <span class="line" style="margin-bottom: 0;"></span>
</button>

     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-color" [routerLink]="['./']">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-color" [routerLink]="['./visitor/about-us']">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-color" [routerLink]="['./visitor/contact-us']">Contact us</a>
          </li>
          </ul>
```

Any ideas are much appreciated.

PS: NO errors in console

Comment: can you inspect the element class on collapse element is being toggled or not? in real example and in your case both. Might help you out to debug the issue